# Elastic beanstalk dynamically creating and deleting alarms for individual instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I need to create alarms for individual metrics on an instance level, and delete them later, is there a straightforward way to do this through ebextensions or cloudformation?

It is important for the metrics to be at an individual level, i can't use autoscaling group aggregated metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no "straightforward" way to do this. The point of using Autoscaling Groups (ASG) is that you treat all the instances as one entity.

Setting alarms for individual instances in ASG is very problematic, as instance in ASG can be added, removed and replaced automatically. Any alarms created for instances that are present today in ASG, may be invalid tomorrow when ASG will change the instances. You would end up with a bunch of invalid alarms in your CloudWatch pretty, which in long therm, would require you to design a solution to manage cleaning the dead alarms.